# How to create a PeopleEditor?

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint-2007, activedirectorymembership

I am building a windows application that upload documents to sharepoint document library and modify its column.
My problem is that i'm uploading a file to document libary that has a people editor column.
To solve my problem I want to pop up a windows form containing a people editor so users can pick the users or groups to fill in the column.

**How can i create a people editor like the one in sharepoint?**

Answer (score 2):

In your asp.net page, you can have PeopleEditor control as simple as this this:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<SharePoint:PeopleEditor runat="server" ID="peopleEditor" 
        AutoPostBack="true" AllowEmpty="false" SelectionSet="User,SecGroup,SPGroup" 
        BorderWidth="1" PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor="false" Rows="1" />
```

Comment: i'm developing a windows application.
I want to do like the sharepoint PeopleEditor mentioned above but in windows application.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a read-only RichTextBox to display the names, and have a ListBox or something showing the names of people from your domain.  You can use classes from the [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.aspx) to do Active Directory lookups.  This is meant to replace the old LDAP queries that were very tedious in getting names from Active Directory.  I haven't used it yet, but I hear it's pretty simple to work with.